# How do i make a command with multiple words in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a command in Discord.py which allows more than one word. However, i am not using @client.command(). I am using `elif message.content.startswith('command in here')` but im not sure how to do it.

I have put my code below if it is any help to anyone who can answer this. I am happy to give people code if it helps. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please add your code to the post, thanks. Also, refer to [how to ask](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=how+to+post+in+stack)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is right.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
if message.content.startswith("test 1234"):
    await message.channel.send("Test passed!")
```

And since is not a client.command make sure to put your bot's prefix before `test 1234`

Comment: thanks. Would I have to put a ‘_’ in between the first and second word?

Comment: No, as you can you see in the example, i only typed "test 1234" without "_"